# Architechture python +flask and spring boot +java

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, rest, flask

I would know how to describe this archtechture as a backend I used spring boot, java, flask and python to deploy rest api and as a frontend I used angular is it a mircoservices architechture ?

Comment: U have java and python for backend

Comment: yes i used both

Comment: why you use both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Is it a microservices architecture ?" -

It is not possible to say from the limited information you have provided.

There is no single canonical definition of Microservices; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).  So deciding whether a system is implementing a Microservices architecture is always somewhat subjective.

What you have described in your Question matches a couple of the bullet points in the Wikipedia page:

- The components are process that communicate over a network using a technology agnostic protocol.
- The components are implemented in multiple languages.

But these are not sufficient to say one way or another.  The other things that matter include the granularity of the services, whether they can be developed independently, whether they can be deployed and used independently, and so on.

My advice would be to read the descriptions for Microservices, then come to your own conclusion.